# Discord.js: setParent() is not a function but in the docs it shows it is

Tags: node.js, discord.js

In my discord server I'm creating a bot for some channels I created and when I got to set the parent it says it's not a function. (same with `setName()`):

```
function chCreate(name, data, type) {
    const ch = message.guild.createChannel(name.concat(data), {type: type});
    ch.setParent(ct.id);
    return(ch);
};

const c1 = chCreate("Member count: ", mcount, "voice");
const c2 = chCreate("Bot count: ", bcount, "voice");
```

in my logs it shows this:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: ch.setParent is not a function
```

Comment: [`createChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=createChannel) returns a `Promise<(CategoryChannel|TextChannel|VoiceChannel)>` which is why it's returning that `setParent` is not a function. You need to handle that Promise before you get your channel.

Comment: thanks, I'll try that out.

Comment: This github issue discusses the exact same thing. https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/2644

Comment: So I handled the promise being returned but now I am just getting a `TypeError: c1.setParent is not a function`

Comment: It doesn't seem like you handled the promise correctly. Please edit the question with your latest attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Channel create return a promise, so you need use `crete.channel.then(=>`

```
function chCreate(name, data, type) {
    const ch = message.guild.createChannel(name.concat(data), {type: type}).then(channel => {
        channel.setParent(ct.id);
    })
};
```